# System.Reflection.AmbiguousMatchException

Tags: wpf

I added Designer support for my control.

I got the following exception when setting the property value like below.

var colStyle = visibleColumn.Properties["PropertyName"].SetValue(Value);

The same above code works fine for VS 2010 project

but it shows the following exception for VS 2008 project

InnerException: System.Reflection.AmbiguousMatchException
       Message="Ambiguous match found."
       Source="mscorlib"

Answer (score 4):

Just a wild guess, but this may be due to a derived class having a property that is hiding the base class implementation, confusing the reflection mechanism.

If you use `GetType().GetProperty(propertyName, BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly).SetValue(target, value, null)` it may fix the problem.